# Excel SQL VBA: adding more than one cmd parameter

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

I am writing SQL-query, and I get error with string value:

```vb
Dim cn As Object, rs As Object, output As String, sql As String
Dim dt As Date
Dim lne As String
Const adCmdText As Integer = 1, adDate As Integer = 7, adChar As Integer = 8
 
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" _
                    & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" _
                    & "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
    .Open
End With

With Worksheets("Page 2")
     dt = CDate(Replace(.Cells(i, 2).Value, ".", "-"))
     lne = .Cells(2, 1).Value ' lne = mystr
End With

sql = "SELECT Name, SUM(Worktime) as summa FROM [Page 1$] WHERE DateTime = ? AND Line = " & lne & " GROUP BY Name"
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cn
    .CommandText = sql
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("dt", adDate, 1, , dt)
    
    Set rs = .Execute ' ERROR: One or more required parameters are missing a value.
End With
```

I tried to add more than one cmd parameter to solve this problem:

```vb
sql = "SELECT Name, SUM(Worktime) as summa FROM [Page 1$] WHERE DateTime = ? AND Line = ? GROUP BY Name"

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cn
    .CommandText = sql
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("dt", adDate, 1, , dt)
    
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("lne", adChar, 2, , lne)
    
    Set rs = .Execute
End With
```

But I also get an error. How do I set more than one cmd parameter and use it in my query?

Table I am working with: [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NgcB2pm6xDVDn8W-lInOMUMxDag1q5ZD/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: For second code block, you say *But I also get an error.* Is this the same error? If not, post its message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter to `CreateParameter` are

```vb
command.CreateParameter (Name, Type, Direction, Size, Value)
```

The `Direction` - parameter should be `adParamInput` (that is a 1) for all parameters

My experience is that for a string parameter (`adChar`), you need to provide the size (length of the string).

Try

```vb
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("lne", adChar, adParamInput, len(lne), lne)
```

Comment: Its important to note, that the size of the string is restricted by the FieldSize in the Database. If `len(lne) > max_field_size` you will get an error.

Comment: @MG92: Had no problem with that using SQL server and Oracle, and I doubt it will be a problem using Excel as database. Of course it will give an error when you use the parameter in an Insert or Update statement.

Comment: We had some issues when using a Access-DB. When a field is initialized with varchar(32) and a parameter was added with a size bigger than 32, we received an error.